# Why does the spring backend keep giving me the whitelabel error of incompatible type?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have a springboot backend with embedded thymeleaf template. However the backend keeps giving me the whitelabel error page: 400 Bad Request, 
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "list". I wish to know why?

I tried changing the id of the user from Long to Double, but it does not fix anything, my backend works for other routes, for example: it prints "hello world" when I visit /hello, which is another route I had written.

```
// this is my user controller class
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView list(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userList", userRepository.listUsers());
        model.addAttribute("title", "user management");
        return new ModelAndView("users/list", "userModel", model);
    }


// this is my repository implementation class
@Repository
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {
    private static final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();
    private final ConcurrentMap<Long, User> userMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public User saveOrUpdateUser(User user) {
        Long id = user.getId();
        if(id == null) {
            id = counter.incrementAndGet();
            user.setId(id);
        }
        this.userMap.put(id, user);
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(Long id) {
        this.userMap.remove(id);

    }

    @Override
    public User getUserById(Long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.userMap.get(id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> listUsers() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new ArrayList<User>(this.userMap.values());
    }

}

// the page I wish to render
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html   xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
        xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
        <title>Thymeleaf in action</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div th:replace="~{fragments/header :: header}"></div>
        <div th:replace="~{fragments/header :: footer}"></div>
    </body>
</html>

// the user object class
package com.waylau.spring.boot.blog.domain;

public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(Long id, String name, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}

// my build class with gradle
buildscript {
    repositories {
        //mavenCentral()

    }

    //ext['thymeleaf.version'] = '3.0.3.RELEASE'
    //ext['thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version'] = '2.2.0'

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.21.RELEASE'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

group = 'com.waylau.spring.boot.blog'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

}
```

Comment: in your application.properties file add this line "server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false" .......it will show full error message on you browser....it may help you to find the problem.......

Comment: I'm appreciating your efforts, Here you can look at your exception _Failed to convert the value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException_ It is clearly mentioned that you backend needs Long Type of value but Your front part is sending String type of value check and verify the request parameter you are sending from the front side. And if it doesn't help you then change the data type from Long to String while getting parameter from the front and then convert String to Long By using Parse Methods.